# How to combine python and robotframework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to make my own keywords in python. How can I connect python and robotframework ? I know I need to import python library/file with my functions. But How I can connect selenium webdriver with that scripts ?

For example:
I want to have function to only push buttons with no locator needed.
I am using selenium webdriver for it.
How I can use it without calling 2 webdrivers?

I have robot test:

```
test something -> my_own_keyword -> more robot tests
```

I have python file.py"

```
def press_button(button):
    ...
    ...
```

I need to make my python+selenium function work in robot.

Comment: It's quite hard to understand you. Can you provide piece of your `Python` code where you stuck or at least pseudo-code you want to implement?

Comment: I do not have code.

I have robot test, and I need to add some features that selenium2library doesn't have.
  I want to use python + selenium webdriver to make new keyword.
But in selenium webdriver you call webdriver, and i want to use that one already created by robotframework.. I know hard to understand,

Comment: This is all described very nicely in the robot framework user guide. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries

Comment: If you're wanting to write keywords that can work with selenium, you might want to consider the [PageObjectLibrary](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-pageobjectlibrary). It makes it easy to write keywords that can directly call the selenium API against the browser opened with the Selenium2Library keywords.

Comment: nice thanks, PageObjectLibrary looks good ;)

Answer (score 1):

In order to start developing custom libraries, it is good to have a decent understanding of Robot Framework itself. This is no different for what approach you take, it assumes that you understand the regular application before extending it.

The same applies to extending an existing library. You should understand the programming language you're about to program in but also understand the library you're about to extend.

Only when the above to items are in place can you really expect to build what you're aiming for.

In the event that you have a passing understanding of plain Robot Framework in combination with Selenium2Library and a decent understanding of Python then I recommend you do the following.

1. Setup your Python development environment. I.e. Install PyCharm or PyDev (Eclipse) and ensure that you have a working Python environment that works with a hello world example.
2. Understand Python [Virtual Environment](http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-pip-virtualenv-installation-on-windows/) and have it setup.
3. Create a new project and develop a standard Robot Framework Library. Ensure that you can debug the python code in the python debugger. When working in Eclipse with [RED](https://github.com/nokia/RED) and [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org/) extensions installed you can use this [guide](https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/red_help/user_guide/python_red_debug.html.md) to set that up.
4. Uninstall the Selenium2Library from python using PIP. Create a new project in your Python IDE, download and extract the [Selenium2library](https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library) code from GitHub in the new project. Install the Selenium2Library in development mode using `python /.../Selenium2Library/setup.py develop`. This will allow you to adjust the existing code and have it active in Python without the need for reinstalling.

From this point onwards you may want to start experimenting with your own functionality and only use your own version in production. The downside of this will be that any update of Selenium2Library will require a merge with your own code.

However, if you want to create a new library extension you may want to take inspiration from [Extended Selenium2Library](https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-extendedselenium2library) on how to do that. This will allow you to make use of any updates without merging. However, it will require some overhead of creating a new library.

Comment: First thing is that I already have all of this set.
Then, I am currently using this extended selenium library cause it provides AngularJS synchronization support and other things i need.
I just needed my own function to be imported into my project. 
I will use Page object library from advice from Bryan, but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your Library with path into Settings in your robot file.

`*** Settings ***
Library             ./libraries/extendedLibrary.py`

Create your new Keyword in that file extendedLibrary.py

`def Capitalize_String(string):
    string = string.capitalize()
    return string`

After that you can use your own new keyword in robot file.

`${string_with_capitals}=   Capitalize_String   all small letters`

As a result, you will have variable in Robot Framework string_with_capitals which is equal to "All small letters"